# Angular2+Webpack , loads styles twice at the head

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to use universal + webpack with Angular2.
But I can't figure out why styles are getting loaded twice at the head element.

This is the git repo where I forked from and I haven't changed a thing !.
https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.git

I can write the codes here but It'll become a mess .

Bellow is my console screenshot that shows the same style being loaded twice :

[image]

Can anyone explain how Angular2 behaves with css ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue...

Comment: I had this issue and resolved it by changing `ViewEncapsulation.None` to `Default` or somehing. Anything but `None`.

Comment: I had this issue, but wanted to leave ViewEncapsulation set to None in the app.component.ts, turns out thought that I was bringing in a high level stylesheet (LESS) in the stylesUrls of my app component. Once I took that out and let the webpack bundle it for me, I stopped getting duplicate styles everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at the repo (I have an assumption for what is the problem at the end), but answering your question about how angular behaves with css:

There are multiple ways to insert a styles into your angular

## Style insertion

***1-  Component Inline Style***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    styles: [`
        p {
            color: #999;
        }'],
    template: '<p>Hello World</p>'
})
```

***2- External Style Sheet***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    styleUrls: ['./styles.css'],
    template: '<p>Hello World</p>'
})
```

***3- Template Inline Style***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `
        <style>
            p {
                color: #888;
            }
        </style>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    `,
})
```

In these 3 methods all your styles are going to be put in the head of the produced html.

***4- Html inline Style***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: '<p style="color: #999;">Hello World</p>'
})
```

The style will remain in the tag and will only be applied to this specific part of the component

## View Encapsulation

for the first 3 types according to the *encapsulation* the styles are either going to be applied to the whole app or only one component

***ViewEncapsulation.None*** Nothing special done by angular 2

***ViewEncapsulation.Native*** Angular 2 uses the idea of the shadow DOM and applies these styles to it's component only

***ViewEncapsulation.Emulated*** `The default view encapsulation` Angular 2 tries to emulate the idea of the shadow DOM by adding some identifying classes to the content of the component and styling them ( .succ-message[_ngcontent-usm-6] {...} )

to apply the view encapsulation

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from @angular/core;

@component({
   selector: ...
   template: ...
   styles: ... (or styleUrls)
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

#### My assumption

Probably you'll find that the styles are included in two different components.